# How to parse date format using JSON API plugin 1.0.7?

Tags: json, wordpress

I'm using the JSON API plugin to display my blog posts on my mobile website. I've got everything working as I'd like, however the the date displays in this format:

```
 2012-03-21 20:03:30
```

However, I'd like it to display like so. Or something similar.:

```
 March 21, 2012
```

This is the Javascript I'm using to display the blog posts:

```
 var MYBLOG_LIMIT = 7;
    var MYWRAPPER_CLASS = 'homeblog';

    var WP={open:function(b){var a={posts:function(){var d=MYBLOG_LIMIT;var e=0;var c={all:function(g){var f=b+"/api/get_recent_posts/";f+="?count="+d+"&page="+e+"&callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(f,function(l){var k=l.posts;for(var j=0;j<k.length;j++){var h=k[j];h.createComment=function(i,m){i.postId=h.id;a.comments().create(i,m)}}g(k)})},findBySlug:function(f,h){var g=b+"/api/get_post/";g+="?slug="+f+"&callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(g,function(i){h(i.post)})},limit:function(f){d=f;return c},page:function(f){e=f;return c}};return c},pages:function(){var c={findBySlug:function(d,f){var e=b+"/api/get_page/";e+="?slug="+d+"&callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(e,function(g){f(g.page)})}};return c},categories:function(){var c={all:function(e){var d=b+"/api/get_category_index/";d+="?callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(d,function(f){e(f.categories)})}};return c},tags:function(){var c={all:function(e){var d=b+"/api/get_tag_index/";d+="?callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(d,function(f){e(f.tags)})}};return c},comments:function(){var c={create:function(f,e){var d=b+"/api/submit_comment/";d+="?post_id="+f.postId+"&name="+f.name+"&email="+f.email+"&content="+f.content+"&callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(d,function(g){e(g)})}};return c}};return a}};

var blog = WP.open('http://www.endofphotography.com/');

    blog.posts().all(function(posts){
        for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
            jQuery('.'+MYWRAPPER_CLASS).append(function(){
        return (posts[i].content) ? '<div class="lastpost_title" href="'+posts[i].url+'"><h4>'+posts[i].title+'</h4></div><div href="'+posts[i].url+'">'+posts[i].content+'<br>'+posts[i].date+'</div><br><hr><br>' : '<div href="'+posts[i].url+'"><h4>'+posts[i].date+'</h4></div>';
     });
   }
 });
```

I've scoured the web for an answer and Stack Overflow as well, but I believe the solution is going to be 'hacking' the plugin somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue.  I had success on Desktop using [jQuery-DateFormat](http://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)
Had issues with this working on mobile, but that was calling with AJAX

```
$.getJSON('http://feed_url/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
   var output='';
   var date = data.post.date;
   var date = $.format.date(date, "MM/dd/yyyy");
   output += '<em>' + data.post.date + '</em>';
});
```

Yours would look something like:
var date = $.format.date(date, "ddd d, yyyy");

Comment: I recently tried to use this script for a web app where I'm using the JSON plugin to show posts dynamically, but unfortunately was not able to get this to work. This SHOULD work though. If it isn't correct, it's really close. Maybe one day I'll finally sort it out.